# Good state of the art document about Algo Trading systems

Tags: algorithmic-trading

I'm currently working on the requirements phase of a software project, and need get an overview of the industry regarding the tools available for Algo Trading.

My first idea was to look for Gartner's Magic Quadrant for Trading Platforms. But I wonder if there is abetter document out there.